# Why is copy assigment possible, if a class has only a (templated) move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, move-assignment-operator

I have stumbled over code today, that I don't understand. Please consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    template <class Type>
    Type& operator=(Type&& theOther)
    {
        text = std::forward<Type>(theOther).text;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::string text;
};

class B
{
public:
    B& operator=(B&& theOther)
    {
        text = std::forward<B>(theOther).text;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::string text;
};

int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2;
    a2 = a1;

    B b1;
    B b2;
    b2 = b1;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, MinGW-w64/g++ 10.2 states:

```
..\src\Main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\Main.cpp:41:7: error: use of deleted function 'B& B::operator=(const B&)'
   41 |  b2 = b1;
      |       ^~
..\src\Main.cpp:19:7: note: 'B& B::operator=(const B&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'B' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
   19 | class B
      |       ^
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:419: Main.o] Error 1
```

I fully understand the error message. But I don't understand why I don't get the same message with class `A`. Isn't the templated move assignment operator also a move assignment operator? Why then is the copy assignment operator not deleted? Is this well-written code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't the templated move assignment operator also a move assignment operator?

No, it's not considered as [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).

(emphasis mine)

> A move assignment operator of class T is a **non-template** non-static member function with the name `operator=` that takes exactly one parameter of type `T&&`, `const T&&`, `volatile T&&`, or `const volatile T&&`.

As the effect, `A` still has the implicitly-declared copy/move assignment operator.

BTW: Your template assignment operator takes [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), it could accept both lvalue and rvalue. In `a2 = a1;`, it wins against the generated copy assignment operator in overload resolution and gets called.

Answer (score 5):

As complement to @songyuanyao's standard-based answer: these kind of language rules are common reasons for guidelines such as MISRA/AUTOSAR (language guidelines for safety-critical C++ development) to have "avoid developer confusion" rules such as:

> (from *[AUTOSAR C++14 Guidelines](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf)*)
>
> **Rule A14-5-1 (required, implementation, automated)**
>
> A template constructor shall not participate in overload resolution
> for a single argument of the enclosing class type.
>
> **Rationale**
>
> A template constructor is never a copy or move constructor and
> therefore **doesn’t prevent the implicit definition of a copy or move
> constructor even if the template constructor looks similar and might
> easily be confused.** At the same time, copy or move operations do not
> necessarily only use a copy or move constructor, but go through the
> normal overload resolution process to find the best matching function
> to use. This can cause confusion in the following cases:
>
> - a template constructor that looks like a copy/move constructor is not selected
> - for a copy/move operation because the compiler has generated an implicit copy/move constructor as well a template constructor is
>   selected in preference over a copy/move constructor because the
>   template constructor is a better match
>
> To avoid these confusing situations, template constructors shall not
> participate in overload resolution for a single argument of the
> enclosing class type to avoid a template constructor being selected
> for a copy/move operation. It also makes it clear that the constructor
> is not a copy/move constructor and that it does not prevent the
> implicit generation of copy/move constructors.
>
> **Rule M14-5-3 (required, implementation, automated)**
>
> A copy assignment operator shall be declared when there is a template
> assignment operator with a parameter that is a generic parameter.

Namely that it can be surprising for developers that a template copy/move ctor/assignment operator does not suppress (/does not "activate" rule of 5) implicitly-generated ones. You are typically required to use SFINAE to make sure that the templated ctor/assignment op does not act *as if* it was a copy/move ctor/assignment by allowing the overload to be active for a single argument of the enclosing class.